# Which ad network suits best for Admob mediation in my country

Tags: android, admob

I am developing an app that shows ads using Admob. However, It turned out that to show ***rewarded interstitial ads***  I have to configure third-party ad networks. How can I determine which third-party ad network gives high eCPM rates *for my country* and for the *type of app* I'm developing?

Comment: I am not sure if this fits this network. It is not exactly about implementation problems. I think it fits better into the *Programmer* Network

Answer (score 0):

would be good to know, what kind of app u have. checked your profile and as i understood, your country is Uzbekistan, but its much more important which geos does your app cover. i'd suggest trying mopub, startapp, applovin, facebook, amazon that work standardly good in almost all geos. moreover there are  cool mediation solutions alongside with admob mediation and some form the pool of networks automatically, analyzing your traffic, so that you don't need to make your own demand source selection